# Puppeteer : use second match with page.evaluate

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

i'm using puppeteer to retrieve datas online, and facing an issue.

Two functions have the same name and return serialized object, the first one returns an empty object, but the second one does contains the datas i'm targeting.

My question is, how can I proceed to select the second occurence of the function instead of the first one, which return an empty object.

Thanks.

My code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const Variants = require('./variants.js');
const Feedback = require('./feedback.js');

async function Scraper(productId, feedbackLimit) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  /** Scrape page for details */
  await page.goto(`${productId}`);
  const data = (await page.evaluate()).match(/window.runParams = {"result/)

  const data = data.items

 await page.close();
 await browser.close();


  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

module.exports = Scraper;
```

Website source code :

```
window.runParams = {};
window.runParams = {"resultCount":19449,"seoFeaturedSnippet":};
```

Comment: Use regex to match the 'runParams' function, and just take the second match. Search how to use 'matches' with regex.

Comment: i tried this, but no luck : const data = (await page.evaluate()).match(/window.runParams = {"result/)

Comment: Can you provide the full code? I'll try to help

Comment: I just edited the post to display the full code

Comment: Can you please add the full value of 'data'?

Comment: console.log(data) does not output anything, it's pretty weird

Comment: Try await this.page.content();

Comment: same result, however page.content(); works

Comment: Try change the function to:
const Scraper = async (productId, feedbackLimit) => {
// ALL PUPPETER LOGIC HERE
};

Comment: await page.goto(`${productId}`); is the URL? did you check it's a valid URL?

Comment: Yes it is for sure, as I do succeed to get the datas, I also checked using my browser and source code visualisation

Comment: await page.goto(`${productId}`); and then await page.content();

Comment: Try again my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, it should work.

```
const data = await page.content();
const regexp = /window.runParams/g;
const matches = string.matchAll(regexp);
    
for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(match);
  console.log(match.index)
}
```

Comment: Wouhou, it works !, i'm able to find the datas; Thank you so much !!

Comment: Glad to help :)